# Installing .package file in Arch Linux

Tags: linux, arch-linux

I'm looking to install [Yenka](http://www.yenka.com/en/Free_student_home_licences/), the successor to Crocodile Clips (electronics simulation software). I was initially going to use WINE, but it seems they offer a linux option, too.

However, the download is for a `.package` file, and I have absolutely no idea how it works. There seems to be very little about it on Google, and I'm not even sure if it's compatible with arch, so I'm not sure where to go from here.

Any advice?

Comment: Have you tried following the instructions on their page http://www.yenka.com/en/Installing_on_Linux/#InstallingonLinux-InstallingYenka? Or are you asking how to install it using the arch package management(pacman)?

Answer (score 2):

Usually, a .package file is produced by Autopackage.
To install it type:

```
. ./filename.package
```

where `filename.package` is the name of the package file.

Answer (score 0):

To execute it you have to type:

```
./filename.package
```

if it says you dont have permission then you need to make the package executable by typing:

```
sudo chmod +x filename.package
```

then try executing it again

once you do that just follow through the instructions given while yenka is being setup and it should finish the installation and add yenka to your applications menu :)

PS:This might only be for me but when I installed yenka on my arch linux pc it crashed after a few seconds so maybe using wine might be a better choice if this also happens to you.